# Is "the fact that" always singular?

Tags: verb-agreement

"The fact that he slept with the victim and his knife had blood *was* enough evidence for him to be the culprit."

Why does it seem like you never use the plural "facts" in these sentences even when you're referring to multiple facts?

Comment: See 1.3 definition. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fact.

Comment: @Wuvex Please give (or link to) an example of a sentence that uses "the fact that" to refer to multiple facts.

Comment: The example I've given has two facts, namely, "he slept with the victim" and "his knife had blood," yet the singular "fact" is used.

Comment: *"The fact that"* appears to be a set phrase. You don't need to worry about plurals here. And sometimes *"the facts don't add up"* is used as a set phrase.

Answer (score 1):

*The fact that* is not a constituent, so it can't be singular or plural. What **is** singular is the noun *fact*.
*That* is the introduction to a conjoined clause (*that  he slept with the victim and his knife had blood*),
which modifies *fact*.

That whole noun phrase

- *the fact that he slept with the victim and his knife had blood*

is singular (because *fact* is singular and it's the head noun of the noun phrase).

One could also say

- *the facts that he slept with the victim and his knife had blood*

since there are two facts. But, just to be clear what's being pluralized when using the plural, I'd repeat *that* after *and*, and maybe add a comma.

- *the facts that he slept with the victim, and that his knife had blood*

Answer (score -1):

According to the Oxford Dictionary[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fact), the word 'Fact' is a mass noun.

Wikipedia[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun):

> In linguistics, a mass noun, uncountable noun, or non-count noun is a noun with the syntactic property that any quantity of it is treated as an undifferentiated unit, rather than as something with discrete subsets

This is why you rarely see the word 'fact' pluralised.

Comment: 'Fact' is commonly used as a count noun. For example: "The facts indicate...", "These two facts suggest...", "Those are the facts".

Comment: The word 'fact' **is** pluralised in NVZ's last comment above.  "*The facts don't add up*" is a relatively common phrase, as is "*These are the facts ...*"

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary link is just indicating that it's a mass noun in the set phrase ***body of fact***, not that it is *ordinarily* a mass noun.